# Stop Filezilla from auto close after process completed

Tags: filezilla

Filezilla get close when any process completed
this issue starts after I update my Ubuntu to 20.04

When I try to edit the file it just downloads and get closed automatically. I want to stop this issue, it is been making my work very hard.

FileZilla version is : 3.46.3

I had also updated it to version 3.48.1
but the issue remains the same

Also, I tried to this solution found here which say change default file type to binary
but that also didn't work for me.

Comment: HI, perhaps you can be more precise on how you updated it, add an link to the solution you found and perhaps what exactly the issue is ... does the connection close, or does the program close ... also it might be helpful if you start filezilla in the terminal, so you can see if any errors get printed -- peace